# How to dIsable automatic install of printers in network?

Tags: networking, printer, network-printer

Is it possible to hide a printer from the network or configure the router, in order to print from specific computers that have the printer installed manually and prevent from being automatically installed on every computer or mac that connects to the specific network?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more as to what exactly is happening? Are your computers finding and installing any and all network printers and you want to stop this? Are your computers part of a domain that uses Group Policy to automatically add printers?

Comment: I use no domain. Yes, computers are finding and installing any and all network printers, that's what i want to stop. I have two printers that are installed on the network. On several occassions i had laptops, pc's or macbooks from friends at my place in order to help them and try to fix whatever problems they had. Almost in everytime, my printers got installed. I know i could turn off network sharing on every computer but it's not the best solution. Sometimes i forget to do it, sometimes friends comes over and access my network so i can't control that. Is there any other way to stop this?

Comment: On the assumption that you are running Windows, try this. In the Start menu Search box (Cortana in Win10), type "change device installation settings". In the window that opens, select "Never install", or "No" in Win10.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the permissions on the shared printer and therefore allow or deny users and groups to install the printer. That should do the trick. If that is not what you meant, you should rewrite your question.